# SqlClient.SqlCommand Bombing Out

Tags: asp.net, sql, ado.net

Still new to .NET, but this looks OK to me. I can't figure out what's going on. I'm trying to add 1 parameter to a SqlCommand. It is an integer in SQL Server, and I'm passing an integer to it.

It hangs on the `Command.Parameters.Add(PolicyNo)` code line and kicks out an "unable to process due to internal error".

I've also tried

> Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PolicyNumber", PolicyNo)

But to no avail. It bombs out with the same error message. Here's the code:

```vb
Public Function GetPolicyObj(ByVal PolicyNo As Integer) As PolicyInfo Implements ILetterWriter.GetPolicyObj
    Dim SQLcon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection

    'Establish the connection
    SQLcon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Hosed;Initial Catalog=MyCat;User ID=Goofy;Password=OpenSesame;"
    SQLcon.Open()

    Using Command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("sp_GetPolicyInfo", SQLcon)
        Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Command.Parameters.Add(PolicyNo) 'Bombs on this line
        Command.Connection.Open()
        Dim reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = Command.ExecuteReader
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried creating the parameter like this:

```
    Dim param as new SqlParameter()
    param.ParameterName = "ParamName"
    param.Value         = PolicyNo
    Command.Parameters.Add(param)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is the problem should be, but you are not giving the parameter object a name, only passing the value which will thrown an exception, you have to give the parameter a name as well

```
Command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("PolicyNo",PolicyNo))
```

Answer (score 0):

Command.Parameters.Add() takes a SqlParameter object as its parameter.  So you can't just send the integer.

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PolicyNo", PolicyNo);
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that but it still bombed out (see text above code). But thanks!

Comment: The error is still the same? In your code you are adding an Integer, .Add is expecting a SqlParameter... Also Command.Connection.Open() is redundant...unless its a VB.NET thing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try explicitly typing your parameter:

```
Command.Parameters.Add("@PolicyNumber", SqlDbType.Int)
Command.Parameters("@PolicyNumber").Value = PolicyNo
```

And make sure your parameter name and datatype match what's in the stored procedure.